# Silverlight Image Get Source From Location Plus Text Inside Textbox (www.abc.com/photos/111.jpg)

Tags: silverlight, image, listbox, location, selectedindexchanged

I am using the following code to place an image inside an imagebox in a WinForm application. The form has a listbox with people's names. As the user selects a name the textboxes and imagebox shows the person's details. The code provides the location/folder of the images and adds the ID number from the "ID textbox" followed by ".jpg" to complete the location.

WinForm Code:
peopleDetailsPhotoImg.Load(@"http://www.abc.com/OA/Photos/" + peopleDetailsIDTxt.Text + ".jpg");

I need the same functionality within a new Silverlight application. I can't figure how to code the same type of location. I need "folder location" + "textbox.text" + ".jpg". Get errors with the formating when trying to use multiple " " and + marks within the location line.

The Silverlight app works fine using the listbox and multiple textboxes that fill as the user selects a name however the ability to use the location + ID + .jpg has me at a stand still!

Any help would be appreciated.

Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `String.Concat(@"http://www.abc.com/OA/Photos/", textbox.Text, ".jpg")`

Comment: <Image Canvas.Left="195" Canvas.Top="93" Height="178" Name="peopleDetailsPhotoImg" Source="http://www.abc.com/OA/Photos/111.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Width="169" />

Comment: Dave, The code above is within my XAML code. This is my first Silverlight/XAML project... My knowledge is limited. I understand your answer is what I am looking for however I am left to whin where/how to "plug it in". I am reviewing String.Concat now on Google however if you could expand your answer for how the code is placed within XAML would be great. I could include more of my code if needed however it is a basic listbox with names and textbox, imagebox that shows details. The textboxes are working fine it the image using text from the ID textbox to complete location/file name that is issue

Comment: Based on what you've said there are a few solutions. If your using the MVVM pattern then you can use data binding to get the textbox value in the view model layer and then concat the string into a new property to bind to the image source. Secondly if you don't mind using the code behind you can attach to the `TextChanged` event on the textbox and then manually set the image source. Thirdly you can element bind the image source property to the text of the textbox via a converter. As this is your first project I'd recommend the first MVVM option using data binding.

Comment: Thank you Dave. In my WinForms app I used code behind after starting with binding and finding I needed more control. I found binding in SL RIA to work well thus far and was thinking of continuing to bind however dont want to "hit a wall" later in the project. One last question... given I used a great deal of code behind in a WinForm/SQL/C#/WebServerDatabase would I be better off to take the code behind step now or get everything working with binding and move needed parts to code later if problems?

Comment: Completely up to you about when you do it, personally I'd do it sooner rather than later... The pattern's there for a reason! Glad I could help